# how to use html_safe in meta tag og:description content in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-share, html-safe

I use og:description meta tag like this

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<%= @post.description.html_safe %>" />
```

But it shows description of post in top of the page.

Comment: You shouldn't use html_safe insinde of the meta tag. It breaks the tag if html tags are stored in @post.description.

Comment: strip_tags might be useful in this case. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags

Comment: strip_tags doesn't work.

Comment: https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/08/28/ruby-on-rails-why-do-we-need-to-html_safe-string-why-html-tags-not-rendered/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ever got this error in my php code to show og file. I thought, It will work to in rails. You just change `""` into `''`

```
<meta property="og:description" content='<%= @post.description.html_safe %>'/>
```

or

```
<meta property="og:description" content='<%= @post.description %>'/>
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Okay. Nice to help. :)